# Nginx Routing on IP address

Tags: nginx

I have my domain example.com, so when someone hits on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com the request is automatically directed to https://example.com - which works fine. However, when I use IP address of the node app 1.2.3.4 it doesn't route to https://example.com which is SSL enabled. If I use the IP address, it shows me the same page but without the padlock icon.

So how do I route a request to https://example.com when someone enters the IP address of node app?

My Node JS APP is hosted on AWS EC2 instance, I have also installed ssl using certbot (LetsEncrpyt). This is my nginx file.

```
 events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
 
  include    conf/mime.types;
  include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  include    /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  index    index.html index.htm;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


# Settings for normal server listening on port 80
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  # location / {
  # }
  # Redirect non-https traffic to https
  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
server {
  listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You should restore the default `server` block that shipped with nginx. It prevents access to your server with invalid hostnames.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am new to Nginx and server setup in general, If possible can you point out a link or article which can help me with default server block code? I don't know how it looks like. I followed up some tutorial and modified the code that you see in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure listening on the server ip adress and then filter after host header and send a 301 redirect for example:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
 
 
  index    index.html index.htm;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


# Settings for normal server listening on port 80
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com 1.2.3.4;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  # location / {
  # }
  # Redirect non-https traffic to https

  if ($host = 1.2.3.4){
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
  }

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
server {
  listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com 1.2.3.4;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";

  if ($host = $server_addr){
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
  }


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I was just trying out the script that you pasted, I got an error "Invalid parameter $server_addr"  On this line  >> listen       [::]:80 default_server $server_addr;

Comment: sorry men. I made a mistake when copying. $server_addr should be part of server_name directive not listen. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, the error did go away. However the redirection is still not working I guees. if I type 1.2.3.4 it is not taking me to https://example.com . I can still page as unsecure, no padlock icon.  What am I missing?

Comment: Two things I would check then: 1)Is there a listen directive configured in the configuration files you including. 2) does your host has multiple ip addresses? If so try hardcodong 1.2.3.4 instead of $server_addr

Comment: Awesome man!  you rightly pointed out the issue, hardcoding the IP address fixed the issue, I removed the includes, the config files. I edited your answer and marked it as accepted

Comment: Thx for your mark. No problem!

Comment: Noticed a strange thing, Only chrome shows the padlock icon, but firefox and edge still displays a security warning.  Any idea why?